# Navigation bar/menu getting disappeared on smaller screen - CSS issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am in middle of developing a website and I am facing a small problem. The top navigation bar of the website works fine upto a particular screen resolution. However, if I adjust my browser window (smaller in size), the navigation bar is getting disappeared. The same problem also persist if I view the website on my Ipad. I am not able to figure out what am I doing wrong with the CSS code for navigation menu.

I have uploaded the website on a testing server

http://bcklight.hostoi.com/

HTML Code

```
<section id="start" class="start">
       <div id="section-nav" class="section-nav">
          <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li><a href="#start" id="link-start">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#process" id="link-process">Product&amp;Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#portfolio" id="link-portfolio">Work</a></li>
              <li><a href="#team" id="link-company">Company</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact" id="link-contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="fn/index.html">Fi</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="index.html">En</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS Code

```
.container{
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:960px;
    padding:0 5%;
    width:90%
    }

.section-nav{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #111;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #111;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #111;
    color:#838383;
    display:none;
    font:800 .688em "proxima-nova",sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:.3em;height:31px;line-height:31px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:9999
    }

.section-nav.fixed{
    position:fixed
    }

.section-nav ul{
    clear:both;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
    }

.section-nav li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 3%
    }

.section-nav li.active a{
    color:#f7e442;
    text-decoration:none
    }

.section-nav a{
    -webkit-transition:400ms;
    -moz-transition:400ms;
    -o-transition:400ms;
    transition:400ms;
    color:#838383;
    font-weight:700;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none
    }

.section-nav a.active,.section-nav a:hover{
    color:#FF8C00;
    text-decoration:none
    }

.nav-trigger{
    text-indent:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:yellow;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    float:right;
    height:16px;
    margin-top:7px;
    width:16px
    }

.section-header{
    font:800 1.875em "proxima-nova",sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:10px;
    margin:0 0 20%;
    padding-left:10px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase
    }
```

Please have a look at inspect element on the browser if I am missing anything to mention over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what's the problem - you're using "**display: none**;" on both

```
media="screen, projection"
.section-nav
```

and then (when it get's even smaller):

```
media="screen, projection"
screen.css:2057@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
.section-nav .nav { display: none; }
```

i think you've got messed up with all the media queries and lost track of what does what :) happens to me all the time. you just need to use Chrome Inspector to figure those out ;-)

http://someimage.com/nFKmzAA

Comment: oh, and as a general advise, think your media queries through on paper first, and then code it ;)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I guess I am messed up with media queries :) Got lost in many media attributes. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: like i said, happens to me all the time :)) some people have brains for math, and some for art. it's hard to keep so much code in your head when you're actually an artist :)) if you going to continue write code, you might want to try SASS. it keeps things more organized. good luck

Answer (score 1):

Position fixed has very [poor support](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/) on mobile browsers.

You should use a media query to change it from position fixed to position absolute on mobile browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Since the problem is not only limited to mobile browsers. Even on web browsers after a certain screen size the navigation menu is not visible. 

I tried adding the media query for section-nav 

media only screen and (min-width:1200px){
 .section-nav{
  display:block;
  position:absolute
  }

However, the issue still not resolved.

Comment: ah, sorry. I didn't spot the display: none in your css.

Answer (score 0):

**in screen.css, line 93**

.section-nav{
display:none;}

display none makes this issue.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had to change the display attribute at two places. One is mentioned by you and another one is at media query for navigation section.